# '$' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: node.js, windows, command-line, npm

I have search quite extensively for an answer to this question and have not found one that address my particular issue. It involves the command line in windows. I am trying to follow a tutorial on using npm. All of the commands in this tutorial begins with $ this symbol, the dollar sign. When I type '$ npm config list' to get the configuration I get the not recognize message. Other similar questions describe other symbols or commands but not the '$' dollar sign. If anyone else has experienced this particular problem and solved it. I would appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: You trying to use jquery inside your node project ?

Comment: I'm not trying to use any particular program. I'm just trying to follow a tutorial on using node project manager. There are other projects that use the windows command line that use the '$' symbol. I assume many window users have used the '$' on the command line. I like to know how I can use it too.

Comment: No, $ is not required. In tutorial, they will just have it for different platform, simply npm should be enough. i believe you're using $ to execute node commands in terminal

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just write 'npm config list' ignore the $

Comment: I get it. It worked. Now can I assume no windows command can begin with the '$' sign. I ask because I see a lot of commands in programming that begin with the '$' sign.

Comment: Yea on Linux people are used to seeing 'user@COMPUTER:~$' so they add the $ to represent that.

Answer (score 0):

**$** is the bash for the UNIX based operating systems. You define your variables by

```
varname = 'name'
```

and then you refer to it in your code by:

```
$varname
```

For the windows, specifically command prompt you define your variable by **SET**
command

```
SET varnme = 'name'
```

and you refer to it by **%%**

```
%varname%
```