# generating SSH key for github: "zsh: command not found: $"

Tags: macos, github, ssh, iterm

I'm trying to configure github with my macOS system. I use iTerm and zsh. When I try to generate a new ssh key according to the instructions from the https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent#generating-a-new-ssh-key I get an error "zsh: command not found: $". Please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['$' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41915762/is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Comment: This is a valid problem. I ran this into myself on a fresh OS installation on Macbook. My first step was to ssh from default terminal. Well, Macbook M1 has Rosetta for that support. First ssh timed out so it is supported. As soon as I followed the steps in the guide it blowed away! `zsh: command not found: ssh`

Comment: I am wondering @mentol if you solved this?

Answer (score 17):

`$` is what you see in sh. In zsh you probably see `[path@user] $` or something like that. You just mustn't copy this dollar sign. What you copy should by ONLY:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"
```

Answer (score 4):

Runing it in bash instead works for me
`exec bash`
then
`ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/id_ed25519`

And you can switch back to zsh by
`exec zsh`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

avoid copying dollar sign while generation ssh keys.
use this ----> ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"

Comment: Please avoid posting answers that are similar to pre-existing ones.