# zsh: permission denied: /Users/myName

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh, access-denied

I am new to programming and I was trying to add the SSH key to my GitHub account (using mac interface). And when I was trying to copy the generated key using the command:

~ pbcopy < ~/testkey.pub
It was showing me this error
zsh: permission denied: /Users/myName

Someone please help me.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't want that `~` at the beginning of the command. `~` is a shell shorthand for your home directory, and if that's the first thing on the command line the shell will try to execute that as a command... and you can't execute directories. Did you copy this from somewhere? If so, they were probably using that as a stand-in for the shell prompt (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41915762/is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command) for a similar situation).

Comment: @NidhiSinha : Please format the commands in your posting, so that they use fixed font (not proportional), as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: First time being here. will be mindful next time

Comment: @GordonDavisson Thank you for your suggestion. it helped. however, I wonder why do I get this issue: zsh: permission denied: /Users/myName whenever I enter this ~

Answer (score 1):

In a basic shell command, the first "word" is the name of the program to run (i.e. the name of the executable that'll actually perform the command). For example, if you run the command `ls -l ~/testkey.pub`, it actually runs a program named "ls" (probably in the /bin directory, so its full path is /bin/ls), and passes it the arguments "-l" and "/Users/myName/testkey.pub".

"Wait", I hear you say, "where'd that '/Users/myName' bit come from?" Well, `~` is shell shorthand for the path to your home directory, and when the shell sees it as part of a command (well, depending on the exact context), it'll replace it with the path to your home directory. Thus, `~/testkey.pub` gets expanded to `/Users/myName/testkey.pub`. Try it with `echo ~` and you'll see what I mean.

Now, when you try to run the command

```
~ pbcopy < ~/testkey.pub
```

the shell expands out the `~`s, giving:

```
/Users/myName pbcopy < /Users/myName/testkey.pub
```

and since "/Users/myName" is the first word of this command, it tries to execute that as a program. But your home directory isn't an executable program, it's a directory, and you aren't allowed to execute directories, so you get a permissions error.

I'm pretty sure the `~` isn't actually supposed to be part of the command at all. I think you just want to run:

```
pbcopy < ~/testkey.pub
```

...which runs the /usr/bin/pbcopy executable, and feeds it input from the file /Users/myName/testkey.pub.